# dotnet core UseStaticFiles index fallback

Tags: .net-core, static-files

I have this `Configure` method in my Startup.cs.
It does 3 things :

- serve static files under wwwroot
- add CSP header for index.html
- serve parameters via /settings.json route

```
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
      {
         if (env.IsDevelopment())
         {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
         }

         app.UseHttpsRedirection();

         // Defaults to index.html
         var defaultFilesOptions = new DefaultFilesOptions();
         defaultFilesOptions.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
         defaultFilesOptions.DefaultFileNames.Add("index.html");
         app.UseDefaultFiles(defaultFilesOptions);

         var staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
         {
            OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
            {
               // Add CSP for index.html
               if (ctx.File.Name == "index.html")
               {
                  ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append(
                     "Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'" // etc
                  );
               }
            }
         };

         app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions); // wwwroot

         app.UseRouting();

         app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
         {
            // Settings.json endpoint
            endpoints.MapGet("/settings.json", async context =>
            {
               string json = $@"
                {{
                   ""myConfig"": ""{_configuration["myParameter"]}""
                }}";
               await context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
            });
         });
      }
   }
```

The files under wwwroot are in fact a vue.js app with routing. I need to return `index.html` for all inexistant request, for the client routing to take control of the page.

Currently it returns a 404 and does not pass in `OnPrepareResponse` hook.

How can I configure index fallback for the router to work in history mode ?
I think it is acheivable by configuration in web.config, but I'd prefer to configure this in Startup.js so this is all in the same place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing a file provider that does the index fallback. It encapsulate a `PhysicalFileProvider`, and return `index.html` under certain conditions if the file is not found. In my case conditions are based on folders css, img or js.

It is implemented this way :

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using System.Linq;

public class IndexFallbackFileProvider : IFileProvider
{
   private readonly PhysicalFileProvider _innerProvider;

   public IndexFallbackFileProvider(PhysicalFileProvider physicalFileProvider)
   {
      _innerProvider = physicalFileProvider;    
   }

   public IDirectoryContents GetDirectoryContents(string subpath)
   {
      return _innerProvider.GetDirectoryContents(subpath);
   }

   public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath)
   {
      var fileInfo = _innerProvider.GetFileInfo(subpath);
      if(!fileInfo.Exists && MustFallbackToIndex(subpath))
      {
         if(!_staticFilesFolders.Any(f => subpath.Contains(f)))
         {
            fileInfo = _innerProvider.GetFileInfo("/index.html");
         }         
      }

      return fileInfo;
   }

   // Plain 404 are OK for css, img, js.
   private static string[] _staticFilesFolders = new string[] { "/css/", "/img/", "/js/" };
   private static bool MustFallbackToIndex(string subpath)
   {
      return !_staticFilesFolders.Any(f => subpath.Contains(f));
   }

   public IChangeToken Watch(string filter)
   {
      return _innerProvider.Watch(filter);
   }
}
```

Then, in startup.config, I use this provider.
Plus, I had to set `ServeUnknownFileTypes` to `true` to respond to requests to a `/path/without/extension`.

```
var physicalFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot"));
var fileProvider = new IndexFallbackFileProvider(physicalFileProvider);

var staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
{
   FileProvider = fileProvider,
   ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
};

app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the solution from @Johnny5 but wanted to return the index.html file and any JS or CSS files even though the base directory is wrong when you reload the page.

By stripping off the prefix one directory at a time we can find the files even if they are on a path like `/assets/index-2562.js`.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using System.Linq;

/// <summary>
/// Strips off any directories until it finds a match
/// This allows an SPA to work even after page reload with some SPA path still on the URL
/// </summary>
public class IndexFallbackFileProvider : IFileProvider
{
    private readonly PhysicalFileProvider innerProvider;

    public IndexFallbackFileProvider(PhysicalFileProvider physicalFileProvider)
    {
        innerProvider = physicalFileProvider;
    }

    // For an SPA we may be called with a path like /foo/bar left over from some earlier SPA navigation
    // We need to remove these prefix directories until we find a match

    public IDirectoryContents GetDirectoryContents(string path)
    {
        string subpath = path.TrimStart(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);  // remove leading /
        while (true)
        {
            var result = innerProvider.GetDirectoryContents(subpath);
            if (result.Exists) return result;

            string? directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(subpath);
            if (directory is null) break;

            int index = directory.IndexOf(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
            if (index < 0) break;

            subpath = subpath.Substring(index + 1);
        }
        return innerProvider.GetDirectoryContents("");
    }

    public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string path)
    {
        string subpath = path.TrimStart(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);  // remove leading /
        while (true)
        {
            var result = innerProvider.GetFileInfo(subpath);
            if (result.Exists) return result;

            string? directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(subpath);
            if (directory is null) break;

            int index = directory.IndexOf(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
            if (index < 0) break;

            subpath = subpath.Substring(index + 1);
        }
        return innerProvider.GetFileInfo("index.html");
    }

    public IChangeToken Watch(string filter)
    {
        return innerProvider.Watch(filter);
    }
}
```

Same startup code:

```
var physicalFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot"));
var fileProvider = new IndexFallbackFileProvider(physicalFileProvider);

var staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
{
   FileProvider = fileProvider,
   ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
};

app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);
```